# libnvrtc.so.8.0 missing on Google Colab (needed by mxnet)

Tags: python, cuda, mxnet, google-colaboratory

I installed mxnet using

```
!pip install mxnet-cu80
```

However when I try to `import mxnet` I get error complaining that `libnvrtc.so.8.0` is missing. Searching for it by `!find / -name 'libnvrtc.*'` returns nothing. Searching by google reveals that [NVRTC](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/nvrtc/index.html) is part of cuda toolkit. I have tried with both python 2 and 3 runtimes. The GPU acceleration is enabled.

What can I do to make mxnet working?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To get the missing library run

```
!apt install libnvrtc8.0
```

After that `!find / -name 'libnvrtc.*'` returns

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvrtc.so.8.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvrtc.so.8.0.61
```

and mxnet is working with the python 3 runtime.

Comment: Also note that if you install the CUDA toolkit via any official source,  the nvrtc library is automatically included, and no separate installation is *ever* required

Comment: The answer shows what needs to be done to get mxnet working with python 3 under Google Colab.

Comment: Please remember to come back and accept your answer so that it falls off the unanswered question queue